# Error relating to serial port while compiling the code of openzwave

Tags: command-line, raspberrypi

I had succesfully installed Open-zwave on raspberry with `sudo make` and `sudo make install`. After this I wanted to compile the example in this package (cpp/example and did `make`), but after this it showed me many functions which were not found. This are the errors:

```
Starting MinOZW with OpenZWave Version 1.6-1923-g8cc47f02
2021-05-31 10:29:09.075 Error, Cannot find a path to the configuration files at ../../../config/, Using config/ instead...
2021-05-31 10:29:09.075 Info, Reading config/options.xml for Options
2021-05-31 10:29:09.075 Warning, Failed to Parse options.xml: Failed to open file
2021-05-31 10:29:09.075 Info, Options:
2021-05-31 10:29:09.075 Info,   appendlogfile: false
2021-05-31 10:29:09.075 Info,   associate: true
2021-05-31 10:29:09.075 Info,   assumeawake: true
2021-05-31 10:29:09.075 Info,   autoupdateconfigfile: true
2021-05-31 10:29:09.075 Info,   configpath: config/
2021-05-31 10:29:09.075 Info,   consoleoutput: true
2021-05-31 10:29:09.075 Info,   customsecuredcc: 0x62,0x4c,0x63
2021-05-31 10:29:09.075 Info,   drivermaxattempts: 5
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   dumptrigger: 4
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   dumptriggerlevel: 1
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   enablesis: true
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   enforcesecurereception: true
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   exclude: 
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   include: 
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   includeinstancelabel: true
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   interface: 
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   intervalbetweenpolls: true
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   language: 
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   logfilename: OZW_Log.txt
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   logging: true
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   networkkey: 
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   notifyondriverunload: false
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   notifytransactions: false
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   performreturnroutes: false
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   pollinterval: 500
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   queueloglevel: 9
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   refreshallusercodes: false
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   reloadafterupdate: AWAKE
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   retrytimeout: 10000
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   saveconfiguration: true
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   saveloglevel: 8
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   securitystrategy: SUPPORTED
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   suppressvaluerefresh: false
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   userpath: 
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Info,   validatevaluechanges: true
2021-05-31 10:29:09.076 Always, OpenZwave Version 1.6-1923-g8cc47f02 Starting Up
2021-05-31 10:29:09.078 Info, Loading Localization File config/Localization.xml
2021-05-31 10:29:09.079 Info, Loaded config/Localization.xml With Revision 12
2021-05-31 10:29:09.079 Always, Using Language Localization 
2021-05-31 10:29:09.080 Info, Loading NotificationCCTypes File config/NotificationCCTypes.xml
2021-05-31 10:29:09.080 Info, Loaded config/NotificationCCTypes.xml With Revision 11
2021-05-31 10:29:09.081 Info, Loading SensorMultiLevelCCTypes File config/SensorMultiLevelCCTypes.xml
2021-05-31 10:29:09.081 Info, Loaded config/SensorMultiLevelCCTypes.xml With Revision 4
2021-05-31 10:29:09.081 Info, Setting Up Provided Network Key for Secure Communications
2021-05-31 10:29:09.081 Warning, Failed - Network Key Not Set
2021-05-31 10:29:09.085 Info, Manufacturer_Specific.xml file Revision is 170
2021-05-31 10:29:09.230 Info, Product name collision: SmartCode 910 type 1 id 1 manufacturerid 90, collides with Touchpad Electronic Deadbolt, type 1 id 1 manufacturerid 90
2021-05-31 10:29:09.242 Info, Product name collision: MS11Z type ff00 id ff04 manufacturerid 312, collides with LZW30 Switch, type ff00 id ff04 manufacturerid 312
2021-05-31 10:29:09.274 Info, Product name collision: NAS-CS01Z Curtain Switch type 200 id 102c manufacturerid 258, collides with NAS-SC03ZE Roller Shutter, type 200 id 102c manufacturerid 258
2021-05-31 10:29:09.308 Info, Queuing Lookup on mfs.db.openzwave.com for Node 0
2021-05-31 10:29:09.308 Info,   Opening controller /dev/ttyUSB0
2021-05-31 10:29:09.308 Info, Trying to open serial port /dev/ttyUSB0 (attempt 1)
2021-05-31 10:29:09.308 Info, Starting DNSThread
2021-05-31 10:29:09.308 Info, LookupTxT Checking mfs.db.openzwave.com
2021-05-31 10:29:09.308 Info, mgr,     Added driver for controller /dev/ttyUSB0
2021-05-31 10:29:09.308 Info, Timer: thread starting
2021-05-31 10:29:09.308 Error, ERROR: Cannot open serial port /dev/ttyUSB0. Error code 2
2021-05-31 10:29:09.308 Error, ERROR: Failed to open serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
2021-05-31 10:29:09.308 Warning, WARNING: Failed to init the controller (attempt 0)
2021-05-31 10:29:09.308 Detail, Timer: waiting with timeout -1 ms
2021-05-31 10:29:09.308 Info, Lookup for mfs.db.openzwave.com returned 151
2021-05-31 10:29:14.308 Info,   Opening controller /dev/ttyUSB0
2021-05-31 10:29:14.309 Info, Trying to open serial port /dev/ttyUSB0 (attempt 1)
2021-05-31 10:29:14.309 Error, ERROR: Cannot open serial port /dev/ttyUSB0. Error code 2
2021-05-31 10:29:14.309 Error, ERROR: Failed to open serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
2021-05-31 10:29:14.309 Warning, WARNING: Failed to init the controller (attempt 1)
2021-05-31 10:29:19.309 Info,   Opening controller /dev/ttyUSB0
2021-05-31 10:29:19.309 Info, Trying to open serial port /dev/ttyUSB0 (attempt 1)
2021-05-31 10:29:19.309 Error, ERROR: Cannot open serial port /dev/ttyUSB0. Error code 2
2021-05-31 10:29:19.309 Error, ERROR: Failed to open serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
2021-05-31 10:29:19.309 Warning, WARNING: Failed to init the controller (attempt 2)
2021-05-31 10:29:24.309 Info,   Opening controller /dev/ttyUSB0
2021-05-31 10:29:24.309 Info, Trying to open serial port /dev/ttyUSB0 (attempt 1)
2021-05-31 10:29:24.309 Error, ERROR: Cannot open serial port /dev/ttyUSB0. Error code 2
2021-05-31 10:29:24.309 Error, ERROR: Failed to open serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
2021-05-31 10:29:24.309 Warning, WARNING: Failed to init the controller (attempt 3)
2021-05-31 10:29:29.310 Info,   Opening controller /dev/ttyUSB0
2021-05-31 10:29:29.310 Info, Trying to open serial port /dev/ttyUSB0 (attempt 1)
2021-05-31 10:29:29.310 Error, ERROR: Cannot open serial port /dev/ttyUSB0. Error code 2
2021-05-31 10:29:29.310 Error, ERROR: Failed to open serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
2021-05-31 10:29:29.310 Warning, WARNING: Failed to init the controller (attempt 4)
2021-05-31 10:29:29.310 Detail, contrlr, Notification: DriverFailed: /dev/ttyUSB0
2021-05-31 10:29:29.310 Info, mgr,     Failed to remove driver for controller /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Also, when trying to execute the file MinOZW I get this error

```
 Opening controller /dev/ttyUSB0  Info, Trying to open serial port
 /dev/ttyUSB0 (attempt 1)  Error, ERROR: Cannot open serial port
 /dev/ttyUSB0. Error code 2 Error, ERROR: Failed to open serial port
 /dev/ttyUSB0
```